# Nesting Emotion 10 classes for cascade

Tags: reactjs, emotion

Previously in Emotion 9 you were able to use Emotion class names to take advantage of cascade. You would wrap the emotion const in curly brackets and prefix it with a period, and then dollar sign. For example, you could do this:

```
const child = css`
  color: green;
`;
const parent = css`
  color: red;
  .${child} {
    color: yellow;
  }
`;

<div className={parent}>I am red</div>
<div className={child}>I am green</div>
<div className={parent}>
  <div className={child}>I am yellow</div>
</div>
```

How can I go about achieving this behavior in Emotion 10? That is my question.

The following is further information about what happens when you don't use a period-dollar sign.

---

Now, the following was and is desirable: if no period are used in Emotion 9 or 10, the parent const will inherit the nested const styles. And furthermore, if that nested const then has overriding styles, those would ultimately be inherited by the parent.

```
const child = css`
  color: green;
`;
const parent = css`
  color: red;
`;
<div className={parent}>I am red</div>
<div className={child}>I am green</div>

const child = css`
  color: green;
`;
const parent = css`
  ${child}
`;
<div className={parent}>I am green</div>

const child = css`
  color: green;
`;
const parent = css`
  ${child} {
    color: yellow;
  }
`;
<div className={parent}>I am yellow</div>

const child = css`
  color: green;
`;
const parent = css`
  color: red;
  ${child}
`;
<div className={parent}>I am green</div>

const child = css`
  color: green;
`;
const parent = css`
  color: red;
  ${child} {
    color: yellow;
  }
`;
<div className={parent}>I am yellow</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work, it just doesn't work in CodePen as the output code there has more text tacked onto it, and it hashes the const names all over again. But if you test in your own code base, this does work. I don't like doing it, stepping into the object to get the name in there, it feels hacky. Would like Emotion to have something specific for these instances.

```
const cat = css`
  color: red;
`;
const dog = css`
  color: green;
  .css-${cat.name} {
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  }
`;
```

Comment: This isn't totally safe, mind you. If you are rendering subcomponents, they will not always get the same hashed class name. Additionally it also seems that Emotion will tack on the subcomponents name to the end of the hashed class name to avoid clashing I assume. So, proceed with caution. What I would really like is for Emotion to return the functionality it had in V.9 - an example of which is found in their V9 documentation, last example on this page:

https://5bb1495273f2cf57a2cf39cc--emotion.netlify.com/docs/nested

Comment: This doesn't work in Emotion 11 (only locally).

Comment: @BMCwebdev I saw your post on github issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @jwkoo no I just don’t write CSS with Emotion this way now. I can understand why they moved away from it. If you post a reply or even open an issue and ping me on it I can give you some suggestions to achieve what you are trying to accomplish. Cheers.

Comment: @BMCwebdev oh thanks for your share! so may I ask what alternative you're using then?